# accessing realtime DB from firebase functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

We are using firebase functions and firebase real time DB for our mobile app. We do send emails when someone place an order which is implemented using firebase DB triggers like below:

```
exports.on_order_received = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
        console.log("start of on_order_received")   
...
```

Above trigger works just fine for us. Now, we have some requirement where we do not have a DB trigger in the picture. It's a http request like below

```
exports.daily_sales_report = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    //query data from firebase
```

The question is how do we access the real time db objects here? or in other words how do i get the access to the /orders node ? I tried like below

```
exports.daily_sales_report = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    //query data from firebase
    var ref = functions.database.ref('orders')
    ref.orderByValue().limitToLast(3).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          console.log("The " + data.key + " dinosaur's score is " + data.val());
        });
    })
```

but this does not work. I get error "orderByValue() is not a function"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).  It has the ability to read and write your database.  In fact, when you write a database trigger, the refs it gives you to work with actually come from the Admin SDK, so it's the same API.  You just need to initialize it yourself when using HTTP type functions:

```
// at the top of the file:
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// in your function:
const root = admin.database().ref();
// root is now a Reference to the root of your database.
```

Comment: i kind of guessed it but then i had this question like how it is working with db triggers. glad u answered that as well.

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to use the `admin` and not the `functions` to access the `database()` to read the data.

(Please ensure you've access to `firebase-admin` sdk, use `import` or `require` as appropriate depending on whether you are using TypeScript or JavaScript)

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.    
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

or

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

Try this:

```
exports.daily_sales_report = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    //query data from firebase
    /* Do not use functions */ 
    // var ref = functions.database.ref('orders')
    /* Instead use the admin */
    var ref = admin.database().ref('orders')
    ref.orderByValue().limitToLast(3).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          console.log("The " + data.key + " dinosaur's score is " + data.val());
        });
    })
```

`orderByValue()` is not defined in `functions.database` - but is actually available in `admin.database().ref()`

Comment: I think this is now broken with Admin v11... specific modules need to be imported (such as firebase/app, firebase/credential, etc)

Comment: As of today (Dec 2022), this answer is 4 year old. It is hard to keep track of answers on stackoverflow to update on SDK updates for any BREAKING CHANGES. With new SDK as you rightly pointed out, the imports have to be modular.