# firebase function deploy failed

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to deploy my cloud function on firebase, but I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Invalid Firebase Database URL failed: url argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".
```

I have installed node 14.18.0, firebase 11.0.0, I have read other posts about  similar problems, with no success:
here my code:

```
"use strict";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {db} from "./configs/firebase";
admin.initializeApp();
exports.addAddminRole = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then((user) => {
return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
  admin: true,
}).then(() => {
  return {
    message: ` Success! ${data.email} as been made an admin`,
  };
}).catch((err) => {
  return err;
  });
  });
  });

  exports.addCustomClaim = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then((user) => {
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, data.claim).then(() => {
  return {
    message: ` Success!claim ${Object.keys(data.claim)} 
    as been set on ${data.email}`,
  };
  }).catch((err) => {
  return err;
  });
});
});
exports.insertUser = functions.https.onCall((req)=>{
const reference = "userProfile";

db.ref(reference).push(req).then(()=>{
return {"message": `utente ${req.email} inseerito nel db`};
}).catch((error)=>{
return error;
});
});
```

and here how I initialize the app:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert({
privateKey: functions.config().private.key.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
projectId: functions.config().project.id,
clientEmail: functions.config().client.email,
}),
databaseURL: `https://[${functions.config().project.id}].firebaseio.com`,
});


const db = admin.database();
export {admin, db};
```

this problem appeared the after I set the environment variables in firebase

Comment: If you are deploying to Cloud functions then you don't need to provide credentials yourself. You can simply initialize Admin SDK by `admin.initializeApp()` (if deploying to same project)

Comment: Also, it looks like `databaseURL` is wrong / has brackets in it

Comment: Like the previous comments mentioned, the proper way to initialize Firebase within a Cloud Function would be to use the `firebase-admin` client as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52286572/16929894). Does the error still occur after initializing it like that?