# Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: username is required

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I run `firebase deploy` I get the following output:

```
> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: username is required
```

Which is odd because the same command has been working for weeks. Is there some `"username"` field that I need to put into `firebase.json` or something?

Comment: Any recent changes you made to a function? Also, it could be due to a dependency being outdated. Maybe you updated something and failed to update other packages as well. Another thought is: do you have any functions that utilize the value "username"? It could be the linter didn't pick up on an error you had in your code and finally now is breaking due to that error.

Comment: Hi Adam, do let me know if below recommendations helped or are you looking for some other information.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to initialize Firebase within a Cloud Function would be to use the firebase-admin client as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286303/accessing-realtime-db-from-firebase-functions/52286572#52286572).
I would recommend you try using the below while initializing the app and see if this works:

`import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";`

Another thing to check are the [firebase function dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies) whether they are still built intact.
As seen per your code, it looks like you're trying to use the Cloud Functions for TypeScript, and                 `npm run build -- --watch` takes care of updating the built code as you are coding. Cloud Functions would run with the built JS code and not the TypeScript code.
The problem could be that the setup at the entry point of Cloud Functions is a .ts file and not .js. In your package.json for Functions, you have
`"main": "src/index.ts"`
Try changing it to:
`"main": "lib/index.js"`
That way the entry point of Cloud Functions will be a JavaScript file, and also, will be the JavaScript that was built from your TypeScript code. lib/index.js is used because, by default, that is where the tsc command will build your src/index.ts file into.
Also do check this helpful document for [troubleshooting the function deploy](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#non-default-runtime) issues.